# Dutch dice puzzle

Tags: riddle, pattern

Someone posted this over on Reddit then promptly removed it (I don't think it was someone trying to cheat on a test - seems an unusual question for such a thing), thought thus stack sub might find it amusing:

[image]

The text of the first three panels translates (roughly) to:

- THIS IS:
- *H* holes in the ice
- *P* Polar bears
- *F* fish
- *M* missed the boat

where *H, P, F, M* are the corresponding numbers of each for each panel.

The last panel asks **WHAT IS THIS?**

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is a variation of

> the puzzle known as petals around the rose.
>  This gives us some pretty big hints - though the latter two parts stumped me for a while anyways.

Holes are

> the central pips of each top face of a die.

Polar bears are

> pips that touch a hole. They are looking for fish.

Fish are

> the pips under the ice. That is, pips on the *bottom* faces.

Missed the boat are

> pips on the faces of a standard die that are the top face of no die on the table.

For the fourth set of dice, the results are:

> 3 holes; 10 polar bears; 13 fish; 11 missed the boat

Comment: Same logic I used - the last one had me flummoxed for a bit from wildly overthinking it... well done!