# How many polar bears do you see?

Tags: logical-deduction

The game is in the name of the game - polar bears around an ice hole.

A clue for you to keep you true - like petals around a rose, you can count each bear's nose.

How many polar bears do you see?

[image][image] **-> 2 polar bears**

[image][image] **-> 4 polar bears**

[image][image][image] **-> 0 polar bears**

[image][image] **-> ? polar bears**

Comment: I like it, but when we look at a 2, 4, or 6 face, what do those dots represent?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dutch dice puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/58347)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The answer would be

> 4

Reason

> It depends on the number of circles around a center dot.
>  The three die has two dots around the outside
>  The second one has four around the five die.
> The third does not have dots around a center dot and some die do not have center dots.
> The last one has four dots around the 5 die.

Comment: Nit: “dice” is the plural; “die” is the singular.

Comment: @eggyal Pedantry: "dice" is also singular, meaning a single dice.  See, e.g., https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/dice and https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/dice where the first definition is for a (singular) cube.

Comment: @Rubio: my nit was merely that the answer had them muddled the wrong way around (and “die” spelled incorrectly).  Had it been “dice” throughout, I’d not have said anything.